# git: how can i list new files to add them after?

Tags: git

I have just cloned a repository in my local computer. Then I've created inside the folder a new file. When i run 'git st' the new file does not appear, not even as an untracked file.

How can i list new files I created inside my project, to add them after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you should see the file unless

- the folder holding the file is not yet added to the repo (in that case, you'll see only the folder when typing `git status`)
- the file is contained in a `.gitignore` present in the folder holding the file
- the file is contained in `.gitignore`
- the file is contained in `.git/info/exclude`
- the file is contained in your global `.gitignore` file (check with
  `git config --global core.excludesfile`)

To check whether your file is ignored by one of the `ignore` files, type

```
git status --ignored
```

This will also show ignored files.

Solutions for the five cases:

- when the folder is not yet versioned, add it with `git add folder_name`. This will add the folder and all of it's files (unless they are ignored) to the index.
- when the file is filtered by a `.gitignore`, modify that file so that your file to be added shows up when typing `git status`.

Answer (score 1):

could it be that it is in .gitignore ?